# API not work because of SYMBOL not shows on search

Tags: wavesplatform

We have token with your blockchain on the name of ZORIX and we use this into our website for live price, We found api not work, when we check and found error: {"type":"Error","reason":"no symbol found in whitelist: ZORIX/WAVES"}

ZORIX Symbol not found and without this Symbol we unable to use API.

Comment: Which API endpoint you use? Whatis your asset id? I guess you have to use your assetId instead of ticker (ZORIX).

Comment: http://marketdata.wavesplatform.com/api/ticker/43SjibPyAtSCoLHWD1hYi6hyZFcWFe95efPkpUJzpHyT/WAVES

We was using asset ID, but this is not working now.

Please Guide me ASAP

Comment: Thy this endpoint - http://dexchart-aws-fr-2.wavesnodes.com:6990/